# change webkit css with jquery or css selector

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Can I use jquery to control the look of [custom webkit scrollbars](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)? I'm curious because I would like to change the background color of `::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece` when I hover over `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb`. Perhaps there is a way to do this with CSS. I'm open to either solution! Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 css, I've tried like `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover + ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
background-color:#3f0;
}` using jquery I'm trying to sort or work something out like `$(document).ready(function(){
 $("body ::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece").css({
   "backgroundColor": "#3f0"
 });
});`

Comment: I don't think that jQuery handles browser specific selectors, make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and try setting it in a separate style sheet.

Comment: @maenu yeah, I've done that, and it's just not working. starting to think it's more trouble than it's worth! Thanks though

Comment: The problem is, that jQuery can not select elements that are not represented in the DOM, like the pseudo-elements `:before` or the webkit scrollbar. See [valid jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: @maenu do you know why i can't then do this `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:before{ bacground-color:#f00; }`

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's a **jQuery** way to do this, but in native JavaScript you can manipulate rules on the stylesheet objects directly:

```
document.styleSheets[2].addRule("::-webkit-scrollbar", "width: 300px;");
```

That works fine. You can also remove rules and change rules:
http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/stylesheet.shtml

You could give your `<style>` block a `title` which would make it easy to find in the `styleSheets` array. Something like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    if(sheet.title == 'scrollbar') {
        for(var j = 0; j < sheet.rules.length; j++) {
            var rule = sheet.rules[j];
            if(rule.cssText.match("webkit-scrollbar")) {
                rule.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
            }
        }
    }
} ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nottrobin/hSEzY/1/

Comment: I did give my stylesheet a title: `<link rel="stylesheet" title="scroll_main" type="text/css" href="styles/scroll_main.css?<?=time()?>" />` but the script seems to fail in the second line. it doesn't recognize it. is there another way i should be giving it a title? Thanks!

Comment: that is very cool. really happy to know that actually thank you. unfortunately, since jquery has no way to track a hover event on the scrollbar, there is not way to attach a `::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece` style change to a `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb onHover` :( Though this is still extremely cool.